# What do I have to do to make this file not public?

Tags: ssh, scp, amazon-web-services

I am trying to SCP some files to an AWS server. However, when I type in my command, it tells me that I am `permission denied (publickey)`. I have `chmod 400` ed the key, like Amazon said to. What more do I need to do to make this key private?

Comment: Amazon isn't complaining that you are using a public key instead of a private key, it is complaining that you don't have a private key for the public key that it is expecting. See e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, that is not my issue, as I can `ssh` into my server, just not `scp`

Comment: Then it isn't a key issue. ssh and scp use the same keys.

Comment: @Alex, Why would it then be saying that the key is public?

Comment: @TJonS, it's _not_ saying that the key is public. You are misreading the error message. See for example, https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey